# Background operations during Doze, Sleeping mode on Android 6+

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, intentservice, android-alarms

I created an Android app which send every 5 minutes coordinates to my server, after 6.0 version, when phone go to sleep/doze mode, alarm (I tested every type of alarm) is fired every 1 or 2 hour though app is in whitelist!

I created a firebase notification sending only data which starts services, but result is the same, onMessageReceived is fired for about 10 minutes after screen off and start again when phone wake up... 
I see more and more topic regards this situation, but no one suggests a working solutions.

Someone know a way with which I can send coordinates in background without stop?

Please help me thanks

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot enforce the notification to be displayed at a concrete interval, because system would batch and perform those batched actions during the windows, that happen in certain intervals (that we as developer have no control of).

Comment: I only need a working solution to send coordinates every 5 minutes every time... nothing else! App is always in background....

Comment: Won't geofencing be a better solution for this? Make a geofence and trigger if if the user leaves. That way you can minimze network traffic and server load

Answer (score 0):

@Cristian you need to use JobScheduler to perform background task above API 21 this will work for you refer below link

Here's an example for executing a JobService operation periodically:

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, yourJobService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); 
builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false); 
builder.setRequiresCharging(false); 
builder.setPeriodic(60000); // <<<<----  60 seconds interval

JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-JobScheduler

OR

you can use firebase jobdispatcher it will take care device battery life also and also compatible with up to API 9

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: I created in my location app a Firebase Job Dispatcher as your suggestion, I'm making a test to see if JobService run in doze mode.

Comment: That's sounds nice let's get in touch if you have any issue.

Comment: I tested on my Xiami Redmi 3s with Android 6.0.1, jobService stop after 1 hour in background... when I turned on screen it restarts immediatly! bad doze mode!

Comment: I tested with setAlarmClock every 5 minutes and alarm always fired.. no stop or postpone during doze mode! Is this the unique working method?

Comment: If it is ok with your device battery than it's fine

Comment: I tested for 24 hours, battery start at 37% and later 28%... it seems to be ok! I need to run 24h because this app is used from drivers whom receive alert if they are late cause sleep or something else

Answer (score 0):

I have MyJobService extends JobService

```
String TAG = "heyTaxiLOG";

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    // Do some work here
    Log.d(TAG,"JobService on Start");
    //Start Service extends IntentService
    startService(new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class));
    return false; // Answers the question: "Is there still work going on?"
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    return false; // Answers the question: "Should this job be retried?"
}
```

GPSTracker as IntentService which takes location from Google, no problem with this, is too long for post!

and dispatcher called in OnCreate method in the MainActivity

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    // the JobService that will be called
    .setService(MyJobService.class)
    // uniquely identifies the job
    .setTag("GPS")
    // one-off job
    .setRecurring(true)
    // don't persist past a device reboot
    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
    // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(180, 180))
    // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
    .setReplaceCurrent(true)
    // retry with exponential backoff
    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
    // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
    .setConstraints(
            Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
    )
    //.setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
    .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Firebase Job Dispatcher run ever? also in doze mode?